# Автоматическое копирование файлов с главного сервера на сервер клиента

Tags: php, веб-программирование, apache

Привет всем!

У меня есть главный сервер и несколько клиентских серверов на Virtualbox. Я заливаю файлы на главный сервер (например, файлы лабораторных работ). Далее запускаю клиента. Клиент сравнивает список файлов на своем сервере с главным сервером. Когда есть новый файл, клиент загружает его на свой сервер автоматически.

Как все это реализовать без подтверждения со стороны клиента? Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Повесить rsync на крон

Comment: А можно настроить nfs. Тогда папка будет общая на всех. Соответственно и файлы будут обновляться в обе стороны "практически в real-time".